# How to typecast preprocessor (macros) to output int

Tags: c, casting, c-preprocessor

I have a very simple macro for which I want to typecast its output to `int` only. How to do that?

```
#define Numbits(A) (sizeof(A)*CHAR_BIT)
```

I tried:

```
#define int Numbits(A)({int val; val = sizeof(A)*CHAR_BIT; return val;})
```

but it also doesn't work

Comment: In the second case you are redefining int, which is a mess!!

Comment: Note that the second macro defines `int` as an obscure string starting `Numbits(A)`, which is a really bad idea.  You certainly can't do it quite like that — you might get away with `#define Numbits(A) ({int val; val = sizeof(A)*CHAR_BIT; return val;})` if you only compile with GCC.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If the problem is a warning about comparing signed and unsigned values, this is not the solution. If you think numbits might exceed the capacity of an int, casting to an int is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @rici - issue was I was getting error for the condition when A is greater than int - long, any object  and so on ..Answer from John 3136 removed the error. But from what I read you are saying " casting to an int is undefined behaviour"  - if I am just counting number of bits - how can it lead to undefined behavior - can you please help me understand?

Comment: If `x` won't fit in an `int`, `(int)x` is undefined. (integer overflow). `(unsigned int)x` is well-defined, but probably the wrong value. What error are you trying to work around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you saying that `#define Numbits(A) (int)(sizeof(A)*CHAR_BIT)` didn't work?