# Force Macro to be of unsigned type

Tags: c, macros

I want to force a macro to be of unsigned type I know this is a straight forward operation e.g.

`#define TEST_VALUE_1    100U`

However the value of the macro I am defining is a define in an external driver support pack that can't be modified. Is their a way I can force this to be of unsigned type

`#define TEST_VALUE_1    BSP_DEFINE_1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to typecast preprocessor (macros) to output int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443484/how-to-typecast-preprocessor-macros-to-output-int)

Comment: Just cast it... `((unsigned)BSP_DEFINE_1)`

Comment: `#define TEST_VALUE_1    BSP_DEFINE_1 ## U`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I tried that already but it just appends. compiler complains `error: 'BSP_DEFINE_1U' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: But then, why do you need it? Note that macros don't have types, they're just expanded textually. -- ahh, ok, seems you need some double expansion for that. Still: why?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Have to follow a certain guideline and `Shift and bitwise operations should only be performed on operands of essentially unsigned
type.` is a  rule

Comment: @underscore_d that works thanks. I just taught there may be some macro expansion method.

Comment: @homeGrown there is

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you must force expansion before pasting, e.g. like this:

```
#define VAL 35

#define _PASTE(x,y) x##y
#define PASTE(x,y) _PASTE(x,y)

#define UVAL PASTE(VAL,U)

// expanding UVAL gives 35U
```

If you can't be sure whether the number is already suffixed or not, you should use a cast to be safe. The cast can also be applied in a macro if you want:

```
#define UVAL ((unsigned)(VAL))
```

Comment: Niggle: This doesn't work when there is already a `u` suffix on the original number literal. (The cast works in that case.)

Comment: @MOehm *might* be an issue, I'll add that.

Comment: Neither of these can work in general: VAL might be something like `(1+2)`, or wider than `unsigned int`.